# Query to find "orphaned" rows between cross-referenced tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables (there's more but hopefully the answer to 3 can be scaled easily) and two of the tables (B and C) contain "_id" references (rows) into the other table (A).

Q: I want to find all the entries in (A) (referenced by '_id') which are NOT referenced by B or C (or any other tables with similar relationship).

Here are some exported SQL for the three tables with uninteresting columns removed - (any references to the term "location" should be translated as table "A":

```
CREATE TABLE `A` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `B` (
    `_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `B_A_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Index into location table (aka A) for planting.'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='An entry for each specific planting.';

CREATE TABLE `C` (
  `_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `C_A_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'The location (A) of the marker.',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='List of markers and their data.';
```

I see this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198410/find-orphaned-rows-in-three-tables)  where the Q was asking about 3 tables but the answers provide general syntax for two tables.

Thanks in advance.

I tagged with both [sql] and [mysql] in that it seems a general SQL question but taking note that this is a mysql application.

My attempt produces a correct result but performance woeful:

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM planting,bed,container,irrigation_line,plant_marker,solar WHERE location._id = planting.pt_loc_id OR bed.bd_loc_id = location._id OR container.cn_loc_id = location._id OR irrigation_line.ir_loc_id = location._id OR plant_marker.pm_loc_id = location._id OR solar.so_loc_id = location._id)
```

Comment: Test each possible tables pair in separate query (location and planting, location and bed, and so on..). Separate queries may be UNIONed if you want to use single query. *but the answers provide general syntax for two tables* This is exactly what you need in.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Akina advice, I was able to refactor the original query I had come up with (which took > 25 seconds to execute) to the below query which takes 5 milliseconds.

The general form is as follows (where the `_id` column is used for cross-reference):

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM B WHERE A._id = B.b_A_id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM C ...) AND NOT EXISTS (...D...) AND ...
```

So basically separate the cross reference selects (NEGATED) into a series of `AND`s and the result is correct and swift.  Here is the refactored form of original query:

```
SELECT * FROM location WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM planting WHERE location._id = planting.pt_loc_id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM bed WHERE location._id = bed.bd_loc_id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM container WHERE location._id = container.cn_loc_id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM irrigation_line WHERE location._id = irrigation_line.ir_loc_id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM plant_marker WHERE location._id = plant_marker.pm_loc_id) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT null FROM solar WHERE location._id = solar.so_loc_id)
```

I admit I can't explain the dramatic difference in execution speed - I even tried to add an index on each of the "loc_id" cross-reference columns but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to find "missing" rows from table `b`:

```
SELECT a.id
    FROM a
    LEFT JOIN b ON b.x = a.x
    WHERE b.id IS NULL
```